# Copy files from one AWS account's S3 bucket to another AWS account's S3 bucket + using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to copy files from source AWS account's S3 bucket into destination S3 bucket which is on a different AWS account **using NodeJS** ?

i.e, from S3 in **AWS  Account A** to S3 in **AWS Account B**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [copyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) method?

Use `Bucket` and `Key` to indicate the destination and `CopySource` to indicate the source object. Make sure your creds have permission to both read the source object and write the destination object.

Ideally, improve the security of your copy by asserting the AWS account ID of the destination bucket in `ExpectedBucketOwner`, if you know it.

Here's an untested example:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
  Bucket: 'destbucket', 
  CopySource: 'srcbucket/srcfolder/file.txt', 
  Key: 'destfolder/file.txt'
};

const result = await s3.copyObject(params).promise();
```

If you need to assume a role that allows access to both buckets, then use some variant of this code to get STS credentials and an S3 client object:

```
const sts = new AWS.STS({ region: 'us-west-2' });

const role_params = {
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/yourrole',
  RoleSessionName: 'optional-name',
  ExternalId: 'some-optional-value',
  DurationSeconds: 3600,
};

const res = await sts.assumeRole(role_params).promise();

const cred_params = {
  accessKeyId: res.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: res.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
  sessionToken: res.Credentials.SessionToken,
};

const s3 = await new AWS.S3(cred_params);
```

To understand the permissions needed for cross-account S3 access, see [How can I provide cross-account access to objects that are in Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)

Comment: I am getting access denied issue when tried this code. My backend is running in AWS Lambda

Comment: Have added a link. You need account B to give S3 permission to account A or to the relevant IAM principal (user or role) in account A. And the IAM principal in account B intrinsically needs S3 permissions for the bucket.